# Remove polyline not working outside a function

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, polyline, google-polyline

I am trying to remove polylines in my google map. I have defined a function that adds polylines between two points as follows:

```
    public void addPolylineBetweenTwoPoint(LatLng point1, LatLng point2, int color) {
        PolylineOptions path = new PolylineOptions()
                .color(color)
                .zIndex(10); // Closes the polyline.

        path.add(point1, point2);

        polyline = map.addPolyline(path);
        // polyline.remove();
    }
```

Now, in my program, I am doing as follows:

```
    addPolylineBetweenTwoPoint(startingPointCoordinates, nearestStartingPoint.coordinates, Color.BLUE);
    polyline.remove();
```

The problem is that when I am calling **polyline.remove()** after my function, it is not working and does not remove the polyline. 
But if I uncomment **polyline.remove();** statement in my function, then the polyline is removing correctly. Since my **polyline** object is same, therefore the polyline should be removed in both cases. But I do not know what is the problem.

Moreover, I already have declared polyline and map objects in my class as follows:

```
    public Polyline polyline;
    private GoogleMap map;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure for removing specific polyline is described here:

[Removing a polyline from google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567595/removing-a-polyline-from-google-maps)